# Find all $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^4+x^3-2x^2+3mx-m^2=0$ has only real roots.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, parametric

> Find all $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^4+x^3-2x^2+3mx-m^2=0$ has only real roots.

I have to find $m$ algebraically but I didn't know how and tried to use calculus..

Let $f(x)=x^4+x^3-2x^2+3mx-m^2$. Using the first derivative $f'(x)=4x^3+3x^2-4x+3m$ and if we take $g(x)=4x^3+3x^2-4x=-3m$. **But I think my idea is bad...**

Comment: how about $m=0$?

Comment: @percusse I have to find an *interval* for m, $0$ may work, but it's the only value?

Comment: Then you need an additional *find all $m$...* specifier

Comment: If $m=0$, then $x^4+x^3-2x^2=0$ has $4$ solutions counted with multiplicity, namely: $x=0$, $x=1$, $x=-2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that the given polynomial can be factored as
$$(x^2-x+m)(x^2+2x-m).$$
So it has only real roots if an only if $\Delta_1=1-4m\geq 0$ and $\Delta_2=4+4m\geq 0$.

Comment: That's a really nice observation and from that $m\in[-1,\frac 14]$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Yeah.. but I don't think I would have any change to observe that... can you help me with a "less" creative way of solving this?

Comment: A real quartic can be factored as the product of two quadratics. In this case something like $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$.

Comment: @Legoman Counting multiplicity they are 4. They are all real.

Comment: @RobertZ Yes, they are four as i said in a comment under the question. But I read the wrong stuff, indeed I read that the OP required only one real solution.

Comment: @C.Cristi A "less" creative way is to see the equation in the variable $m$ to be factorized. Then you are working with $m^2 - 3xm + \alpha$. Now find two factors of $\alpha$ whose sum are $-3x$

Comment: @RobertZ $d$ in this case shouldn't be $-m^2$?

Comment: @percusse where $\alpha=x^4+x^3-2x^2$?

Comment: @C.Cristi Yes but I've changed the signs for convenience.

Comment: @percusse What do you mean by "finding 2 factors of $\alpha$ whose sum are -3x"?

Comment: @C.Cristi $b\cdot d=-m^2$

Comment: $(x + p)(x + q) = x^2 + (p + q)x + pq$

Comment: @RobertZ So your $a,b,c,d$ are taken arbitrarily not from $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$?

Comment: @C.Cristi Yes, they are not related with $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$